# How to get the most recently added files in subfolders of an ADLS Gen2 container

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake-gen2

I'm trying to identify/get the most recently added files and accordingly, transfer the information to an Azure SQL Database table. The problem is that the new files are added to subfolders and I don't know how to search within them. Is it possible to search within the subfolders of the container itself?

[image]

[image: @activity('Get ListOfFileNames').output.childItems]

[image: varReferenceDateTime - 1900-01-01 00:00:00 varLatestFileName]

[image]

If this process cannot be achieved with ADF, is there another configuration that I could use?

Comment: Can you add your folder structure? How many levels it is nested?

Comment: container -> subfolder -> list of subfolders

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your folder structure is nested, **Get meta data activity won't recognize the wild card path for the file names**. So, it requires nested pipelines based on the folder level. If the folder level is 2, it requires parent -> pipeline in a loop.

**To avoid this nested pipeline, you can use dataflow**. First **Get all the file paths list in the folder structure using dataflow**. Then pass this list to ForEach with below logic.

```
-> Dataflow activity
-> Foreach
        -> Get meta data activity - for last modified date of file
        -> if activity - check the date
            -> update the file path variable with current file path
            -> update the latest date variable
-> Copy activity - use the latest file path variable in the source file path
```

Give your source dataset path till the container like below.

[image]

Give this dataset to the dataflow, and in dataflow **source settings, use the wild card path `folder/*/*` and add the column `filepath`**.

If you want, you can also add the **Start time**(`subDays(currentUTC(),1`) and **End time**(`currentUTC()`) filters for the files but make sure to change the expression as per your time zone.

[image]

Here whetever might be the file structure, it will merge all the rows of the files and adds a column which has the file path of that particular row like below.

[image]

Now, use aggregate on this. In the **Group by**, use column `filepath` and add any sample column `count` for the aggregate with expression `count(<any column name>)`.

[image]

This will give the result like below.

[image]

Then, use select transformation Rule based transformation, to select only the `filepath` column like below.

[image]

In the dataflow sink, use **sink cache** and select **Write to activity output**.

[image]

In pipeline, take the dataflow activity and give the below configurations.

[image]

If you execute the dataflow activity, it will give the file paths array output like below.

[image]

Give the below expression to the ForEach.

```
@activity('Data flow1').output.runStatus.output.sink1.value
```

Use the above logic to get the latest file now with `@item().filepath` in every iteration.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I think I have set up all the steps correctly according to your description, but there is some issue with the data flow that I don't understand.

Comment: what is the issue? did it gave any error?

Comment: hello, the problem was with the wildcard pattern, I managed to fix it and now it looks like this: subfolder/subfolder/subfolders*/*, but I have another issue with ForEach: Operation on target loopThroughAllTheFiles failed: The expression 'length(activity('Data flow1').output.runStatus.output.Source.value)' cannot be evaluated because property 'output' doesn't exist, available properties are 'ClusterId, sparkVersion, computeAcquisitionDuration, version, profile, metrics, clusterComputeId, dsl'.

Comment: Check the dataflow activity output. Is it giving the above value array in that?

Comment: yes, the result of the data flow is an arrray, I think I'm getting closer by fixing the errors one by one, but now I have an error with the IF condition. This is the expression : @greater(ticks(activity('Get LastModifiedDate').output.lastModified), ticks(formatDateTime(variables('varReferenceDateTime')))) and this is the error: In function 'formatDateTime', the value provided for date time string 'yyyy-mm-dd' was not valid. The datetime string must match ISO 8601 format.

Comment: Use this expression `@greaterOrEquals(ticks(activity('Get Metadata1').output.lastModified), ticks(variables('date')))
`.

Comment: hello, I changed the format of the variable from 'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffffffK' to '2023-10-25T09:13:25Z' and also the expression to the one provided from you and it worked, thank you