# date time string was not valid. The datetime string must match ISO 8601 format

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I can't understand exactly how it should be formatted to avoid this error. I think I've put the expected format, but perhaps the function itself is incorrectly structured. Can someone clarify where exactly the problem is?

[image]

And this is the expression:

@greater(ticks(formatDateTime(activity('GetLastModifiedDate').output.lastModified, 'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffffffK')),ticks(formatDateTime(variables('varReferenceDateTime'), 'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffffffK'))
)]

Since this question is related with another topic, I am including a link.

[How to get the most recently added files in subfolders of an ADLS Gen2 container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77438529/how-to-get-the-most-recently-added-files-in-subfolders-of-an-adls-gen2-container?noredirect=1#comment136520427_77438529)

Comment: @greater(ticks(formatDateTime(activity('GetLastModifiedDate').output.lastModified, 'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffffffK')), ticks(formatDateTime(variables('varReferenceDateTime'), 'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffffffK')))

Comment: Apologies, but I don't see any difference between this expression and the above one.

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs because the value `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss000Z` given to `formatDateTime` is not valid. It should be like this: `2023-10-25T09:13:25Z`. However, in your case, it is the above-mentioned string.

[image]

So, the variable `varReferenceDateTime` does not contain an ISO 8601 string; please check that.

I have provided the string as shown below and ran the pipeline with your expression, and it worked successfully.

[image]

[image]